# Why is my jQuery .mouseleave animation not working?

Tags: jquery

So, I'm fairly new to jQuery.. I'm working on a website, working with `Twitter Bootstrap`. Now I want my menu buttons to sort of pop out when you .`mouseenter`. This works. However I want in to go back to it's original state when .`mouseleave`. Can anyone help?

```
$('.nav-pills li a').not('.nav-pills .active a').mouseenter(function(){
    console.log('enter');
    $(this).animate({
        height: '+=5px',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 300);
});
$('.nav-pills li a').not('.nav-pills .active a').mouseleave(function(){
    console.log('leave');
    $(this).animate({
        height: '-=5px',
        opacity: '0.5'
    }, 300);
});
```

EDIT: Sorry 'bout that.. HTML down here:

```
<div class="container" id="menu">
    <div class="tabbable fixed-top">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Restaurant</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hotel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feesten & vergaderen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nieuwsbrief & activiteiten</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Omgeving & links</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Revieuws / Gastenboek</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `.nav-pills`,`li`,`.active`..?? You need to show your `html` also

Comment: Use Mouse Hover instead of mouse enter event,Please provide your html so that i can make demo for you.

Comment: Using the provided code, I've created a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sqmQr/), but it seems to work as I'd expect. Perhaps you can modify that (add your CSS, any other code, etc) to reproduce the problem you're seeing?

Comment: .nav-tabs, .nav-pills {
    text-align:center;
}
.nav-pills>li>a:hover{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #13A116;
 color: #FFF;
}
.nav-pills>.active>a, .nav-pills>.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>.active>a:focus{
 background-color: #0C610D;
 color: #FFF;
 height: +15px;
 opacity: 1;
}
.nav-pills>li>a{
 color: #13A116;
 opacity: 0.5;
}

Comment: @Thomas What OS and browser (as well as version) are you testing with?

Comment: Windows 7 x32 and Google Chrome 26.0.1410.64 (latest)

Answer (score 0):

-- your code work fine

-- just change  opacity: '1' in mouseleave event

-- Try this

```
$('.nav-pills li a').not('.nav-pills .active a').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '+=5px',
        opacity: '0.5'
    }, 300);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '-=5px',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: That's what I thought. But the .mouseleave is not showing.. Any idea?

Comment: with hover event you will notice the change of event

Comment: Does not work either.. When I use Inspect Element, the numbers show it's animating, but on screen it just goes to natural stage in an instant. Could it have anything to do with css?